# Authenticating with AZURE in an Angular2 SPA and authorizing endpoints in Express

Tags: angular, cordova, azure, express, single-page-application

It is difficult to organize this question because it has many parts.  I'm open for any suggestions on how to word/organize it. Any help in deciphering this would be greatly appreciated!

**Note:**  ***All RESTful services will be on premises.***

This question is in the context of three layers, and how they can utilize Azure for authentication and authorization...  They are as follows:

1. SPA Client using Angular2
2. RESTful Web services with Express
3. Cordova compiled Native Client

I've read the Microsoft white papers about the Azure flows (in particular the SPA - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) ) and have successfully created examples of an SPA client and an express service that authenticates and redirects.  However, the examples that I've been successful with are only with the layers listed above on their own.  What I'm missing is a full example of the above link that gets a token, passes it to the resource from the client, and utilizes Role-based access control (RBAC).

To summarize:

The answer that I'm looking for would include:

1. The correct javascript libraries to use.
2. How to authenticate against AZURE in an app deployed using Cordova.
3. An explanation of how the authorize code and token flow works (in the link for the SPA flow provided, above).
4. An example of a client SPA or native application calling a secured endpoint.
5. An explanation of the difference between a native application and a Web app/API in AZURE in this context.
6. Where does the client secret belong in this flow (I'm assuming only on the express services)?

Comment: You probably want to use [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js), and go through [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/26/using-adal-with-angular2/) for using ADAL with Angular2.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  That's the library and tutorial that I used to get the client working.  I have the client and the service authenticating and getting a token.  There's just not a good example of calling an express endpoint that is set up with Azure using the ADAL for Javascript on the client.

Comment: On organizing this question: I feel like it is too broad right now, maybe you'll have to break it into several smaller questions (point 3., 4. and 5. feel like they could be valuable questions on their own)...

Comment: Thanks, Phonolog.  I believe I'm going to take that approach, asap.